# Ranging beacons in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, ibeacon, appdelegate

I want to rang beacons in the background. With background i mean when the phone goes to lock screen. I want the app to continue ranging beacons. The problem i have now is that the code never finds beacons. I have two beacons who is working but the AppDelegate don't find them. When i run the same code in a ViewController, it finds the beacons and displays them. How can i do it?

```
@interface BDAppDelegate () <AXABeaconManagerDelegate>

@end

@implementation BDAppDelegate {
    NSMutableDictionary *beaconRegions;
    NSMutableDictionary *detectBeacons;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    CLBeaconRegion *beaconRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:[[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"MyUUID"] identifier:@"微信"];

    [AXABeaconManager sharedManager].beaconDelegate = self;
    [[AXABeaconManager sharedManager] requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    [[AXABeaconManager sharedManager] startRangingBeaconsInRegion:beaconRegion];

    self->beaconRegions = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    self->detectBeacons = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    while (detectBeacons.count < 10) {
        NSLog(@"Rows in detectBeacons %lu", (unsigned long)beaconRegions.count);
    }

    self->beaconRegions[beaconRegion] = [NSArray array];
}

- (void)didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region {
    self->beaconRegions[region] = beacons;
    NSMutableArray *allBeacons = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (NSArray *regionResult in [self->beaconRegions allValues])
    {
        [allBeacons addObjectsFromArray:regionResult];
    }

    NSPredicate *pre = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"accuracy != -1"];

    NSArray *rights = [allBeacons filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pre];

    NSString * str = @"accuracy";
    self->detectBeacons[str] = rights;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On iOS, **apps are limited to ranging for 5 seconds in the background**.  This timer is restarted each time the app is put to the background, or when a beacon monitoring event (entered region / exited region) fires.  The good news is that **you can extend the time allowed to range beacons in the background to 3 minutes after each of these events.**

I put together a blog post that shows you how to do it [here.](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2014/11/13/extending-background-ranging-on-ios.html)

Comment: Is there anyway of making it range all the time? I want it to range when the user clicks on a "start button" and stop rang when the user click "Stop". The most important for me is getting the RSSI and  the time.

Comment: The only way you can get it to range all the time is to specify location updates in the “Required background modes” in your Info.plist.  This will then give you *infinite* time to do background ranging with the technique described in the blog post above.  This will work fine if you can install the app via XCode.  If you need to distribute via the AppStore, you will need to convince Apple reviewers that your app is a legitimate location app, otherwise they will not approve it for AppStore distribution with this background mode set.

Comment: So the only thing i need to do is implement the code in appdelegate, turn on the location updates and convince apple and then i have unlimited time? Is there something else i need to do?

Comment: You also need to start the dummy background task as described in the blog post.

Answer (score 0):

For **CLLocationManager** there is a method `startMonitoringForRegion(CLBeaconRegion *):beaconRegion`

which should be added before we start `startRangingBeaconsInRegion`.

So if your AXABeaconManager class is from CLLocationManager add this:

```
[[AXABeaconManager sharedManager] startMonitoringForRegion:beaconRegion];
```

Otherwise:
    Create a CLLocationManager object locationManager and initialize it then add start monitoring like below.

```
[self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:beaconRegion];
```

before you `startRangingBeaconsInRegion`

**Discussion: startMonitoringForRegion**
You must call this method once for each region you want to monitor. If an existing region with the same identifier is already being monitored by the app, the old region is replaced by the new one. The regions you add using this method are shared by all location manager objects in your app and stored in the `monitoredRegions` property.

for more refer [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/startMonitoringForRegion:)

Comment: you don't have to monitor to range

Comment: Is there any way of making the code i have attached to work? I use AXABeacon who is a bit different code and SDK?

Answer (score 0):

**ranging** for beacons is an operation that consumes a lot of battery and iOS won't allow you to do it endlessly in the BG (most of the time. there are cases, where it works)

what you gotta do is call iOS your doing BG work:

```
 UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier token = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
     NSLog(@"Ranging for region %@ killed", region.identifier);
 }];
 if(token == UIBackgroundTaskInvalid) {
     NSLog(@"cant start background task");
 }
```

THEN do whatever

when done, call `endBackgroundTask`

Comment: we are talking about RANGING here -- not monitoring :)